# How do I build the quick access menu in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I need to build it because it has disappeared! I have 1.6.2 CE with Bluescale theme. I cannot launch because of the disappearing menu.

Comment: What is the "quick access menu"?

Comment: @vsushkov It is a bunch of links: My Cart, Login/Logout etc. You can see a sample on: [linl](http://web-experiment.info/magento14/bluescale/)

Answer (score 0):

Originally this block is called `top.links`
It's created in `page.xml`

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
....
</block>
```

Then every block adds link there. For example customer Module:

```
        <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
```

This block is outputed in the `page/html/header.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

So you have to review your `layout` files and `header.phtml` to find where `top.links` are removed or broken. If it doesn't help try debugging of `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the issue is that the theme has a custom top links top.links.custom somehow that is not showing up. Here's the code from local.xml in the theme folder: <reference name="header">
   <remove name="top.links" />
   <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links.custom" as="topLinksCustom"/>

Comment: check if its content is getting outputed in `page/html/header.phtml`.